# Android Facebook asking login every time?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application integrating facebook login, facebook login working fine but its asking login ewvery time.

I logged via facebook login working fine, in my app using app request while app request also asking facebook login.

i want to avoid that tell me some idea to do this,

my code for login:

```
Session.openActiveSession(Notication_Webview.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
@Override
public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(session.isOpened()){

Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(user!=null){

try{            
userName=user.getFirstName();//obj.getString("first_name");
facebookId=user.getId();//obj.getString("id");  
}catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(tag, "getUserIdMethod--->"+e);
}

}
}
});                 
}
}
});
```

In this code for app request,

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Facebook mFb = new Facebook("app id");
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", userIDString);
params.putString("message", Message);
mFb.dialog(this.getParent(), "apprequests",
params, new DialogListener() {

public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onError(DialogError e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onCancel() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

mFb.dialod method:

```
 @Deprecated
    public void dialog(Context context, String action, Bundle parameters, final DialogListener listener) {
        parameters.putString("display", "touch");
        parameters.putString("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI);

        if (action.equals(LOGIN)) {
            parameters.putString("type", "user_agent");
            parameters.putString("client_id", mAppId);
        } else {
            parameters.putString("app_id", mAppId);
            // We do not want to add an access token when displaying the auth dialog.
            if (isSessionValid()) {
                parameters.putString(TOKEN, getAccessToken());
            }
        }

        if (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Util.showAlert(context, "Error", "Application requires permission to access the Internet");
        } else {
            new FbDialog(context, action, parameters, listener).show();
        }
    }
```

tell me how to avoid second login.

Comment: can you post mFb.dialog() method?

Comment: mFb.dialog() is facebook inbuilt method.

Comment: yes i know that is inbulid function if that method have any session?

Comment: check it updated my question added mFb.dialod method

Comment: have you check this for your login button click?  if( !mFacebook.isSessionValid() ) {
       Toast.makeText(currentclass.this, "Authorizing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       mFacebook.authorize(currentclass.this, new String[] { "" }, new LoginDialogListener());
       }
      else {
       Toast.makeText( currentclass.this, "Has valid session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

Answer (score 4):

Once your user is logged in, fetch the **access tokens** and save them in your device using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Next time the user opens your app, open your SharedPreference file and **retrieve** the value of the access tokens from there.

After you retrieve the values from the storage, check if the session is still valid or not using **`isSessionValid()`**.

If the session is still valid then directly login the user (without asking for the details again) and make sure you **update the values of the access tokens** in the SharedPreferences when he is logged in. That way the expiry of the access tokens will be extended every time the user logs in.

Also, do not forget to **`clear()`** the SharedPreference file when the user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

When you logged in session will open,At that time take a static flag and update.Keep go for isSession() after checking the flag.
When you logged out again reset the static flag.

Answer (score -3):

when the user loggin in then store the username and password somewhere. you can use SQLite for this. if hw logging out , destroy that. when the user again open the application check whether there is data in database or not. if yes, then directly pass that to facebook otherwise ask the user to login again.

Comment: Facebook OAuth **does not allow** to store username and password!! It is a huge security risk and thus Facebook does not allow it. You can only store the access tokens and check if the session is still valid or not.